# Can't add anything in my DB C# using ADO Entity

Tags: c#, database

I'm a beginner on Visual Studio so, please, be gentle :)

Here the code i'm using :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (KrqcSDBEntities context = new KrqcSDBEntities())
        {
            activite monActivite = new activite();
            monActivite.lieu_activite = "Paris";
            monActivite.nom_activite = "Natation";
            context.activite.AddObject(monActivite);
            activite test = context.activite.FirstOrDefault(o => o.id == 1);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I succesfully succeed to get value from my DB but i can't add anything in it without any error.

Can you please have a look on it and try to help me ?

It would be very nice !

Thanks you

Comment: Could you share the error you are getting?

Comment: Are you sure the row you are adding has the ID of 1?

Comment: Justin Harvey : I have no error
cederlof : I'm using Server Management Studio to check my DB (I only have one row in my DB [the one i have add manually] :

    activite test = context.activite.FirstOrDefault(o => o.id == 1);

Is just for verify that i can check what is in my DB

Comment: If you are getting no error, yet no row is going in, I would double check your code is definitely pointing at the same DB your Management Studio is.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot Justin, VS was copying my DB in local and then, it wasn't using the right DB !

Answer (score 1):

SaveChanges first, then get the item from data store:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (KrqcSDBEntities context = new KrqcSDBEntities())
    {
        activite monActivite = new activite();
        monActivite.lieu_activite = "Paris";
        monActivite.nom_activite = "Natation";
        context.activite.AddObject(monActivite);
        context.SaveChanges();


        activite test = context.activite.FirstOrDefault(o => o.id == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if i change this (with o.id == 2, cause i already have a row) test = null.